# Products Type : Grouped Product - How can i create discount for grouped product

Tags: magento-1.9, price, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I need to add discounts price for grouped products. eg : item : 1 = 10, item : 2 = 20, when Item  add to cart how can i display total amount is 25(discount is 15 %),

My Workout : 
screen shots :

[image]

[image]

Its Not Working
 i just want to add discount for grouped products, in my grouped products 3 products, front end display normal price, after add to cart the price should be discount 15 %

Comment: Is it possible to write code for associated products of grouped products is try to purchase total amount is less by 15 percentage Note: individual products price is displayed as it is. after adding to cart, then the overall amount is displayed as low as 15 percentage.

Answer (score 1):

Under **Rule Information**, make sure you have the rule status active, the right websites and the right customer groups. Also, double check if you are using coupon codes.

Under **Conditions**, you don't need to specify anything, since you will always have 15% discount for this product. Just remove that condition that you have.

Under **Actions**, you have everything right. Just double check if the SKU is right for the product that you want.

After that, go to `System > Cache Management` and clear all your cache.

**IMPORTANT:** Shopping Cart Price Rules just show the discount in the **Cart Totals** table, NOT on the product.

In my example, I have a product that costs $10.00 and have 10% discount. You see that the product still shows $10, but the Cart Totals table shows the 10% discount:

[image]

If you want the discounted price to show in the product, use `Promotion > Catalog Price Rules` instead of `Shopping Cart Price Rules`.

Comment: @ Bruno Monteiro : Are you using grouped products?

Comment: @ Bruno Monteiro : Normal discount working for me, when i try to discount for grouped product,  i am stuck.  pls check my question, grouped products discount not working.  grouped products within a sku consists two products.

Comment: could u pls join chat

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51923/products-type-grouped-product-how-can-i-create-discount-for-grouped-product

Comment: this is my case

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/wEEQn5L.png

Comment: Hi @JeevaRathinam, did you try to put the individual products SKU instead of the Grouped Product SKU?

Comment: In chat added more details

Comment: @ Bruno Monteiro :    http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51923/products-type-grouped-product-how-can-i-create-discount-for-grouped-product