# Upgrade v1.9.2.2 to v1.9.3.1 locally

Tags: magento-1.9, error, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade a local magento site from v1.9.2.2 to v1.9.3.1.

However, after copying the files from the v1.9.3.1 to my root folder I get this error when trying to access the site :

**Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Help_Mapping' not found in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Data.php on line 35**

Any idea where it comes from and what I can do to fix it ?

Comment: Which way you are using to upgrade, by using magento connect manager its not possible. Some more days to taken by using magento connect manager.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I am doing it manually by unpacking the Magento 1.9.3.1 files into my root folder

Comment: Well I fixed it, just had to recompile. Thanks everyone

Comment: @ arnold : Is it know about discount for grouped products

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152608/discount-price-how-can-give-discounts-for-my-grouped-products