# How can i give discount for random 2 products get 10% discount

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, grand-total, random

If a customer chooses item1 and item 2, get 10 % discount from grant total. How can i give a discount?

Comment: @NitinPawar : Actually i am going to this method for my grouped products discount nnot working,

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152608/products-type-grouped-product-how-can-i-create-discount-for-grouped-product/154983#154983

Comment: i gave discount for my grouped products what you said above, its not working.

Comment: @NitinPawar : I am applied 15 percentage of my two different sku products, but discount amount is higher than what i gave.

Answer (score 0):

For Applying Discount on Grand Total Than You Can Refer Follow Link:

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/

Comment: not for my all products, admin selected products. eg, buy item a and item b is applicable for discount, another one item a and item c there is not applicable for discount.

Comment: you need to set rules for that

Comment: thats what i need