# Buy product X and Y, get a discount of 50% for product Z

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, discount, promotions

Any idea how to do this in promotions from admin panel?

If a customer buys product X and product Y, customer gets a discount of 50% for product Z.

X, Y and Z are specific products.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Products Type : Grouped Product - How can i create discount for grouped product](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152608/products-type-grouped-product-how-can-i-create-discount-for-grouped-product)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extension of **amasty** for this purpose.

[Special Promotions | v1.10.3](https://amasty.com/special-promotions.html)

Link to magento connect : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/special-promotions-by-amasty.html

Comment: Is there a way to do it without an extension?